# Search and replace in current file with Sublime Text plugin

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am trying to port a Sublime Text build system to a plugin.

The build system would receive the current file and go through it with this code:

```
for line in fileinput.input(inplace=1):
    sys.stdout.write(makeReplacements(line))
```

Now, in the plugin syntax I go the fact that the way to get my current file's content is:

```
input = self.view.substr(
  sublime.Region(0, self.view.size())
)
```

But now I'm not sure about what I should do about the next operation.

```
for line in input(inplace=1):
```

How could I make replacements in the file on-the-fly and then save it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @RazerM, the first argument has to be the file path. So for my example, this will work.

```
for line in fileinput.input(self.view.file_name(), inplace=1):
  sys.stdout.write(self.makeReplacements(line))
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>I don't think the Sublime Text plugin API can save the buffer, but you could use the `file_name()` method in the [sublime.View class](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html#sublime.View) and work with the file directly.</s>

As noted by @MattDMo, the file can be saved using `view.run_command('save')`.

It may be easier to use the file name if your old build file worked with that.

Comment: not true. Check out `Packages/Default/save_on_focus_lost.py` for an example of saving a file via a plugin.

Comment: That explains how to save, but how would I output the line to replace the current line? `inplace=1` and `sys.stdout.write(makeReplacements(line))` do not seem to work. Should I store each line in a variable then replace the view's content and the save it?

Comment: The [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) docuumentation indicates that you need to pass the file as the first parameter: `fileinput.input(filename)`. It worked previously because it uses the first command line argument by default.